# Cadastrar e exibir imagem no banco de dados com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, imagem, longblob

Olá,
Gostaria de saber como posso cadastrar uma imagem no banco de dados e como faço para exibi - lá,pesquisei na internet e vi que o campo no banco tem que estar como longblob ou tem poderser varchar,pois assisti em um tutorial em que o cara coloca varchar no campo em que ele salva a imagem.
Obrigado!

Comment: Você usa algum framework ou é com PHP puro?

Comment: Estou usando somente o PHP mesmo.

Comment: Não sei se é possível salvar uma imagem inteira no banco de dados, mas o que geralmente se faz é salvar somente o nome da imagem no banco de dados (com um nome gerado aleatoriamente, pra evitar conflitos) e mover o arquivo para uma pasta. acho que não vou conseguir te ajudar, mas tem este [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) com um tutorial pro PHP 5, talvez seja um bom ponto de partida.

Comment: Ah sim,então no caso eu salvo o nome da imagem,e tenho que ter ela no meu diretório também ? Mais ou menos isso..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, possível é. Existe um tipo de arquivo no MySQL chamado `blob`. 
Já tentei realizar alguns testes de salvar uma imagem dentro do MySQL, nunca funcionou legal, a imagem fica bem distorcida.

O ideial é salvar a url da imagem no banco de dados e fazer upload de arquivo.